# Acknowledgements section of master's thesis

Tags: thesis, acknowledgement, thesis-committee

Besides thanking my thesis advisor, can I acknowledge other professors who have guided me along the way during my master's program or is the acknowledgements section really only for thanking the advisor?

Comment: I guess the norm might depend on your country and even your university. Try to find some other thesis in your department and see how it looks like.

Comment: I think this is a case where you get to decide for yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to peek at a few other examples to make sure there's no institutional norms, but you can often acknowledge whoever you want, and indeed its a good place to acknowledge more personal contributions.

For example, in mine I acknowledge:

- My advisor
- The other members of my committee
- Some colleagues who provided data
- A family member who used to be a member of a profession who I asked a few questions about
- Several fellow students
- My funding sources
- StackOverflow and CrossValidated
- My favorite purveyor of caffeine.

Comment: +1, but I wish I could +2 for the "favorite purveyor of caffeine". Somehow I don't think my advisor would take that well.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think students have a strong tendency to "overacknowledge" in their theses, papers, presentations etc.  After all, a thesis, a paper or a presentation by a student is or should reflect the work of the student, not the work of Peter, Paul and Mary who helped this student.

It's always a matter of personal preferences of course but, aside from those *directly* involved in supporting the results of the thesis or unless you present results as spokesperson for a group, acknowlements are IMO a case where less is more.